# Django not recognizing field override for Current User in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am having an issue in setting the user automatically in django rest framework. In my models.py I have the following:

**Models.py**

```
class Space(models.Model):
   creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class SpaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault()))

    class Meta:
        model = Space
        fields = '__all__'
```

The intent is that the creator field will be set during creation through the API. When I issue a POST request to create the model, i get the following error:

> "IntegrityError at /api/space/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   apiapp_space.creator_id

I assume the serializer is not even using this field override, as when I set null=True in my model, it seems to save correctly with the creator field set to null.

Note that I have also tried using serializers.ModelSerializer.

How can I get django to recognize this field override?

Comment: what about removing `read_only=True`?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge This seems to have done the trick, but seems odd considering they actually recommend using this in the documentation - see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

also id rather not expose the field to the autogenerated API forms at all but I can live with it if I have to!

Comment: Is it worked after removing `read_only=True`?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes it does. However, this allows other users to change this field if they want to, which is undesirable.

Comment: @I posted one answer. Please give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in [the release notes for v3.8](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#380).

For read-only fields you need to pass the value when calling save:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

The `CreateOnlyDefault` is used as the value for the `unique_together` validation on the model.

This was a breaking change in v3.8, required to allow correct behaviour elsewhere. (Previously read-only fields with a default were considered writable, with the default being used as the written value. Ultimately that turned out to be not a good idea.)